# Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf problem odoo v. 11 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, odoo, odoo-11

I have problems for 2 days in installing `ODOO version 11 on ubuntu 16.04`, I have tried in several ways to install, but everything was for nothing. 
I have a serious problem with `wkhtmltopdf`.

I have had several problems with that library

```
Wkhtmltopdf seems to be broken
```

After that error I did this -> 
`sudo apt-get install xvfb libfontconfig wkhtmltopdf`

Then `wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf` to confirm if there is a problem or not.

in console he threw me next.

```
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)
Done
```

I opened the pdf and everything was normal.

But when I return to odoo mail I get the next line.

```
Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

If someone has the secret formula to install odoo version 11, I will be very grateful.

Comment: Which version of `wkhtmltopdf` is installed on your system?

Comment: `wkhtmltopdf --version`

`wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt)`

Answer (score 3):

Get the Odoo suggested binary from wkhtmltopdf website:

```
wget https://downloads.wkhtmltopdf.org/0.12/0.12.5/wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.xenial_amd64.deb
```

Install with following command

```
sudo dpkg -i wkhtmltox_0.12.5-1.xenial_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

The thing is, apt repository doesn't always contain latest version of a package, that may cause issue with your server. Try to stick with the version suggested by odoo itself, which is `0.12.5-1` for latest odoo versions.

Comment: You should always use the same version which Odoo is providing per default. Every version of `wkhtmltopdf` has fixed big problems by opening new ones. You should only use the newest version, if you have the time to check all usages in Odoo ;-)

Comment: How does odoo provide wkhtmltopdf? From my experience, apt repo always contains somewhat older version of wkhtmltopdf, for example ubuntu 16.04 repo contains `0.12.2.4-1` where the latest stable version is `0.12.5-1`. Also never had problem using the latest stable build.

Comment: For example in its dockerfiles: https://github.com/odoo/docker/blob/d3e44ad1f340ceb42ec73c2be5b2d65042fe7a52/12.0/Dockerfile

Comment: Yeah if you look closely, you can find out that odoo is using the same version, the latest stable one.

Comment: Just as example Odoo was using 0.12.1 for ages, because some newer versions of wkhtmltopdf changed a lot in scaling. They are finally using 0.12.5 :-)

Comment: That Odoo isn't using the current stable version wasn't my point. Odoo tests their default reports against a version and sticks to it. That runs like this for 3-4 years, so just using the newest version _could_ be bad. Sorry if I didn't make my point clear enough at first.

Comment: oh yeah I get it. Thanks for information, answer updated.

Comment: Odoo does have [a Wiki about `wkhtmltopdf`](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/wiki/Wkhtmltopdf) and recommended versions, which is quite helpful.